# Using Curly-Curly {{}} in the Argument names_glue of pivot_wider() in a R Function

Tags: r, function, pivot, curly-braces

Hello everyone and thank you in advance for your responses.

Per default, tidyr::pivot_wider() in R creates the new column names with the values from "names_from" in the suffix. This can be changed by including a "names_glue = {var1}_{var2}"-argument (as seen here: [R: Changing column names in pivot_wider() -- suffix to prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63061947/r-changing-column-names-in-pivot-wider-suffix-to-prefix)). However, since I am trying to pivot_wider in a function and I cannot figure out how I need to apply this argument to a curly-curly-variable (see example below).

I need to rename the columns that way so that I can reorder the columns alphabetically later, so that the column with the absolute number and percentage are displayed for Party A first, then for Party B, etc. (instead of all the absolute numbers first and then all the percentages second). Can someone help me?

Example: I have a dataset with political candidates, their party alliance and their sociodemographic information. How many men/women are there overall and per party (in absolute and relative terms)?

```
# Create example data frame:
Datensatz <- data.frame(Kandidat= c("Candidate A", "Candidate B", "Candidate C", "Candidate D"),
                 Partei = c("Party A", "Party B", "Party A", "Party C"),
                 Geschlecht = c("Male", "Female", "Female", "Female"))
Datensatz

# My current function code:
stats_sociodem <- function(data, var, parties){

  # Create tables for statistics overall
  sv_stats_all <- data %>%
    group_by({{var}}) %>%
    summarise(all_n = n()) %>%
    mutate(all_per = prop.table(all_n) * 100)

  # Create table for statistics grouped by parties
  sv_stats <- data %>%
    group_by({{var}}, {{parties}}) %>%
    summarise(n = n()) %>%
    group_by({{parties}}) %>%
    mutate(per = prop.table(n) * 100) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = {{parties}},
                values_from = c("n", "per"),
                names_glue = "{{{parties}}}_{.value}"
                ) %>%
    select({{var}}, sort(names(.)))

  # Join
  var_name <- deparse(substitute(var))
  sv_stats_final <- left_join(sv_stats, sv_stats_all, by=var_name)
sv_stats_final
}

# Application example for gender statistics:
stats_sociodem(Datensatz, Geschlecht, Partei)
```

Maybe I could use regular expressions, but not sure.

Comment: I'm not clear on what the issue is. The argument `names_glue` as you have commented out, would order the variables how you are asking, so what would you like us to do more?

Comment: Also, assigning to the global environment within a function strikes me as a very bad way of running a custom function. Why not just return `sv_stats_final` within the function and then assign it when you call it, i.e. `mydf <- stats_sociodem(...)`?

Comment: I apologize for being unclear. When I run the function as is on an actual dataset of mine, I get an error:

stats_gender <- stats_sociodem(nr23_rec, Geschlecht, Partei)

Error in eval(parse(text = text, keep.source = FALSE), envir) : 
  Object 'parties' not found

Apparently, names_glue doesn't look for "Partei" but for "parties" in this instance, meaning that the {{}} diidn't work? I'm sorry not really good at all of this

Comment: I'm not getting an error with the code as you provided it, hence the confusion. Perhaps amend your code as you intend to use it to produce the error so that we have something to work on for debugging.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I edited the code in my original post and you know should be able to replicate the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were already hinting to a solution when you use `deparse(substitute())` further below.

```
library(tidyverse)

# My current function code:
stats_sociodem <- function(data, var, parties){
  
  # Create tables for statistics overall
  sv_stats_all <- data %>%
    group_by({{var}}) %>%
    summarise(all_n = n()) %>%
    mutate(all_per = prop.table(all_n) * 100)
  
  parties_name <- deparse(substitute(parties)) # New
  
  # Create table for statistics grouped by parties
  sv_stats <- data %>%
    group_by({{var}}, {{parties}}) %>%
    summarise(n = n()) %>%
    group_by({{parties}}) %>%
    mutate(per = prop.table(n) * 100) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = {{parties}},
                values_from = c("n", "per"),
                names_glue = paste0("{", parties_name, "}_{.value}") # New
    ) %>%
    select({{var}}, sort(names(.)))
  
  # Join
  var_name <- deparse(substitute(var))
  sv_stats_final <- left_join(sv_stats, sv_stats_all, by=var_name)
  sv_stats_final
}

# Application example for gender statistics:
stats_sociodem(Datensatz, Geschlecht, Partei)
```